# Delegate not being set correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, inheritance, delegates, delegation

Im working on a project and my UIWebview class needs to execute a method from my DownloadView class

I am using the open source project https://github.com/robertmryan/download-manager

When this code executes the method:

```
 DownloadTableView *download = [[DownloadTableView alloc] init];
 [download queueAndStartDownloads:_downloadURL];
```

This line doesnt set the delegate right

```
  self.downloadManager = [[DownloadManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
```

The whole start download method

```
- (void)queueAndStartDownloads:(NSURL *)url
{


NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *downloadFolder = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloads"];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:downloadFolder])       //Does file exist?
{
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:downloadFolder
                                   withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                    attributes:nil
                                                         error:nil]) {

    }
}

self.downloadManager = [[DownloadManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
self.downloadManager.maxConcurrentDownloads = 4;


    NSString *downloadFilename = [downloadFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]];
    [self.downloadManager addDownloadWithFilename:downloadFilename URL:url];


self.cancelButton.enabled = YES;
self.startDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"DOwnling");
[self.downloadManager start];

}
```

The methods in my DownloadView class wont execute

```
 - (void)didFinishLoadingAllForManager:(DownloadManager *)downloadManager
```

{

Comment: You haven't showed enough code to be able to pinpoint the problem. But in general don't make a "initWithDelegate" method, it is not the usual way of doing things. Use the designated initialiser for your class (or subclass) and assign the delegate after that.

Comment: Im using this guys download manager https://github.com/robertmryan/download-manager

Comment: If a delegate is required then I see nothing wrong with the designated initializer being initWithDelegate.

Comment: You're totally free to ignore conventions, of course. But it helps to do things like Apple and everyone else do them if you want to work with others.

Comment: What does "doesnt set the delegate right" mean to you? What did you expect to happen? What did you observe that surprised you?

Comment: @Jonah the delegate methods dont work like - (void)didFinishLoadingAllForManager:(DownloadManager *)downloadManager
{

Comment: Is your code under ARC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your code is under ARC,  from the code I understand that`DownloadTableView *download` is a local variable. Hence the `DownloadTableView` object gets released after the scope of the method where it is declared ends. Hence the delegate method doesn't get called, because the delegate is released. To avoid this, you can create `DownloadTableView` object as an instance variable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice it works but the table view still doesnt update any idea why?

Comment: Are you calling reloadData?